# Icon align with the text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using linearicons and I was trying to align the icon with the text (vertically) and I just can't figure that out.. Somehow the icon it's not sticked on top of the navbar like the text so I think that might be the problem. 
Here's an image to show you what I'm talking about ->

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7aLY.png

I'm trying to align the icon vertically with the text and then the entire menu with the navbar. I hope you guys will understand.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default top-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="infos pull-right">

      <span class="lnr lnr-clock infos-icons"></span>
      <p class="infos-text">Mon-Fri: 08:00 - 12:00</p>
      <span class="divider-vertical"></span>

      <span class="lnr lnr-envelope infos-icons"></span>
      <p class="infos-text">mail.example.com</p>
      <span class="divider-vertical"></span>

      <span class="lnr lnr-phone infos-icons"></span>
      <p class="infos-text">(880)123-456-7890</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS that I have after trying to align them:

```
.top-bar {
margin-bottom: 0;
border: none;
background-color: #9E87FF;
color: #fff;
height: 50px;
}

.navbar .divider-vertical {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 9px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.infos-text {
    display: inline-block;
}

.infos .infos-icons {
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, when you ask a question please try to make a fiddle. Thank you

Comment: If I try this example it is already vertically aligned...

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS

```
.top-bar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: #9E87FF;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar .divider-vertical {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 9px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.infos-text {
    display: inline-block;

}

.infos .infos-icons {
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;       
    display: inline-block;      
}
```